# Drop down menu gets cut off because of max-width of a parent

Tags: css, wordpress, megamenu

I've integrated the [Mega Menu Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jquery-mega-menu/) into the Wordpress site I'm working on. The last menu item gets truncated, because the main container has `max-width` set. I want the last item to overflow while still keeping the same `max-width`. I've tried setting `overflow-x` and `z-index` on menu `ul`, `li` and main `div` container, but to no avail.

**EDIT**: the parent of the menu had `overlow: hidden`. Setting it to `overflow: inherit` fixed the problem.

Comment: Please read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<div id="wrapper">` is getting `overflow: hidden`. If you remove that your menu will not get cut off.